# Can running object be garbage collected?

Tags: c#

I have a simple class:

```
public class Runner
{
    public void RunAndForget(RunDelegate method)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Run), method);
    }

    private void Run(object o)
    {
        ((RunDelegate )o).Invoke();
    }
}
```

And if I use this like so:

```
private void RunSomethingASync()
{
    Runner runner = new Runner();
    runner.FireAndForget(new RunDelegate(Something));
}
```

Is there any danger using it like this? My C++ guts tell me that runner object should be destroyed after RunSomethingASync is finished. Am I right? What happens then to the method running on different thread?

Or perhaps it is other way around and runner will not be collected? That would be a problem considering I may call RunSomethingASync() many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My C++ guts tell me that runner object should be destroyed after RunSomethingASync is finished. Am I right?

In short, no. .NET garbage collection is not done on a deterministic basis. An object is *eligible* for garbage collection once it is no longer rooted - that is, once no more reference paths to it (from living objects) exist. There is no guarantee that any particular object -- or, indeed, any object at all -- will ever be garbage collected, though it's pretty likely.

However, in your case, your object isn't even eligible. While the object is falling out of scope in your code (so it would appear that no references exist), delegates do contain references to their owning instance (assuming they point to an instance method). A reference to your object will exist until `Run` is called, as the `ThreadPool` is holding on to a reference to the delegate until then, and that delegate has a reference to `Runner`.

So, to answer your question, there is no danger in what you're doing. Because the delegate references the instance, your object cannot and will not be collected until after your operation completes. Once it completes, your object will then be eligible.

Answer (score 5):

The object will not be garbage collected until it is no longer rooted - that is, until all reachable references to it have been removed.  There is an exception to this where if two objects hold references to each other and nothing else holds references to those objects, those two objects are available for Garbage Collection.   Running asynchronous methods like yours holds references to the object and won't be disposed mid call.

A note to a comment below: Calling Dispose() on a method does not force a Garbage Collection on that object.

Since we're talking about Garbage Collection here is a link to the GC.Collect function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx

and the GC class itself:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0fwz4wc(v=VS.100).aspx

EDIT: See Adam's answer about delegates and references to objects.

Comment: That is not very helpful. That is a well known fact.

In my case who is holding reference to Runner object I created?

Comment: Does calling .Dispose() on an IDisposable force garbage collection?

Comment: @Ian no it does not.  You can call dispose on an object and technically keep it around forever.

Comment: @Ian: No, it doesn't. The only way to force garbage collection is to call GC.Collect (which btw you shouldn't)

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all.

Comment: Dispose() is only so the class can clean up any resources it is holding on to (such as closing files, etc.), but the object will still be around until it's garbage collected.

Comment: "until all references to it have been removed" : that's not exactly true... if A and B reference each other, but they're not referenced anywhere else, they are eligible to garbage collection. It doesn't depend on whether references to the object exist, but on whether the object is accessible

Comment: @Thomas, I always forget to include that in part of the description.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joel: It's my understanding that editing an answer in such a way as to change its actual meaning is frowned upon. If an answer is incorrect (or simply inaccurate), let the community vote that way.

Comment: @Joel, if you want to edit my post to make it more correct, please feel free.  I'm not perfect, and I am certainly aware of that.  @Adam editing a post to make it incorrect is definitely frowned upon by the community.

Comment: @Kevin: I rolled back your post to your last version, I didn't edit it. If someone has a correction to make to someone else's (non-CW) answer, it should be offered as a comment or an answer itself. **The entire point of having your own answer is that it's supposed to reflect your own knowledge, not that of someone else.** Editing of others answers is in place to allow for correcting typographical, formatting, and clarity errors, *not* for changing the meaning of the answer (this is spelled out explicitly).

Comment: @Adam: you're taking a few points of rep rather seriously, considering you got 49 votes (and 505 rep) just for saying `while(true)` is better than `for(;;)`.

Comment: @Adam, no the point is to provide an answer for the community.

Comment: @Kevin: That's what community-wiki questions and answers are for. If you wish for your answer to represent the collective knowledge of the community, I would suggest making use of that option in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, object where's is code running can not be collected because, there is several references to the object (for example "this" is reference to the object).

Comment: No, that's not true. An object that is referenced only by itself is not accessible, so it can be collected. However, in that case, the ThreadPool might keep a reference to the object (through the delegate), but I'm not sure about it...

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, the `ThreadPool` holds a reference to the delegate, which holds a reference to the object.

Comment: @Thomas: The "this" reference is available in the stack of the currently running method. The cleaning algorithm is working both with memory for stack and heap.